# Eco Friendly Cleaning Solution

Tags: organic-chemistry, cleaning, environmental-chemistry

I would like to find a solution that can kill roof algae, fungus, mold, mildew effectively without using environmentally unfriendly products but don't know enough about chemistry to make a solution myself.

Comment: How about peroxide?

Comment: This question is a bit broad because "environmentally unfriendly" is not well specified.  For example, algae, fungus, and mold are all naturally found in the environment, and so from a certain perspective, anything that kills them will be environmentally unfriendly.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to stay with commercially available, read-made solutions. These products are thoroughly tested and certified.

They typically contain around 5% of various benzalkonium chlorides, such as N-Myristyl-N-benzyl-N,N-dimethylammonium chloride, as biocides.

**UPDATE** As far as the mildew is concerned: The orange ladybird (16 white spots) and the 22-spot ladybird apparently feed on mildew. If these two are naturally found in your region, get some. This is as eco-friendly as it can get to keep mildew in the garden close to a minumum.